# Stroustrup regex \e

Tags: c++, regex

In A Tour of C++, on page 83, Stroustrup provides the following regular expression:

```
R"((\ew+))"
```

Nowhere in the book is \e defined, and I can't find anything about it on the Internet. What does \e represent in a regular expression?

Comment: I have the book (2nd printing) and it is `R"((\w+))"`. I think it is a typo in your version of printing.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a typo by Stroustrup. `\e` doesn't have any special meaning in regular expressions and doesn't make sense in the context.

If you were to actually compile the example code on the page using

```
R"((\ew+))"
```

wouldn't print anything at all. He probably just wanted to use

```
R"((\w+))"
```

a capture group of 1 or more word characters, which matches the shown output.

[His original regex compiled](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94e6a1291c5bc4dd)

[Compiled after removing the extra 'e'](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e92be65833dfb96)

Comment: I don't see it in the errata; might be worth submitting it to him. http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html

Comment: Indeed, seems like it got fixed between the 1st and 2nd printing without making it into the errata somehow.